# QFileDialog remains open after selection made

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have created a QGIS plugin to import a tab separated value file, using:

```
filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.dlg, "Select file to import ", path, '*.*')
uri="file:///"+filename+"?"+"delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s"%("\t", "Set Grid Easting", "Set Grid Northing")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "SpreadTests", "delimitedtext")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

It works as expected except that the dialog box to select the file stays open after a selection is made.  Is there something I am doing wrong? or something else I need to add?

Comment: Sure it won't be the issue, but looking at my own plugin's use of QFileDialog, I use `self` as the first argument, not `self.dlg' (or equivalent).

Comment: I just tried it without the ".dlg" but get an error as soon as I initiate the plugin, so is there any other difference?

Comment: whereabouts is this code in your plugin? Is it in initGui() or __init__()? Or is it in a method which you've connected to a signal, e.g. when the user clicks a button? I find the latter approach works for me.

Comment: Thanks, Steven.  It looks like you were on the right track, but I got another answer before I could reply to your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing the slot function code with the code necessary for a result. That is the problem.

For example, I created one arbitrary plugin to 'open files'. Next snipped code, at `__init__` method, is for the button to connect with the slot where is the **QFileDialog**:

```
.
.
.
    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.
.
.
.
        #QFileDialog for open file
        self.dlg.lineEdit.clear()
        self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.select_open_file)
.
.
.
```

For convention, the slot function is placed before run method:

```
.
.
.
    def select_open_file(self):

        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.dlg, "Select file to import ", "", '*.*')

        self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename)


    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
.
.
.
```

if result:

```
.
.
.
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.

            filename = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()

            print filename
```

The "something useful here" is to print **open_file** but, in your case, you have to put the code.

```
uri="file:///"+filename+"?"+"delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s"%("\t", "Set Grid Easting", "Set Grid Northing")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "SpreadTests", "delimitedtext")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

It works for me as you can see at the next images:

Selecting the input file:

[image]

After click in 'Open', the **QFileDialog** was closed and the **path** of the shapefile was added to the **QLineEdit**:

[image]

After click in OK, the name of **filename** was printed at the Python Console.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks - I'll have to look up and learn about "slot function code", but when I changed my code as suggested, it's all good now.